# paypal single payout blank response

Tags: php, curl, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I want to integrate paypal's single payout method in my system, as I want to send money to my sellers, when they request for withdrawal. I have generated an "Access token key" for this and making a curl call from PHP script. But the response is a blank string. I have tried `curl_error($curl);` but this also doesn`t do anything. Below is my code

```
// data to be sent
$data = [
            'sender_batch_header' => [
            'email_subject' => "You have a payment",
            'sender_batch_id' => "125458268"

            ],
'items' => [
    [
        'recipient_type' => "EMAIL",
        'amount' => [
            'value' => "12.00",
            'currency' => "USD"
        ],
        'receiver' => 'myselle@gmail.com',
        'note' => 'A trial for single payout',
        'sender_item_id' => "2014031400456"
    ],
],
];

//curl link for single payout with sync off
$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true");
$header = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json", 
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token ,

);

$options = array(
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $header,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => json_encode($values),
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 10
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$rep = curl_exec($curl);

$response = json_decode($rep, true);
curl_close($curl);
```

But here my $rep is a blank string, tried getting single payout details as well, but this also returns blank string...please help..thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of search I found an answer, which was very easy. I didn't use paypal's single payout, instead of that I used it's Implicit Payments operation of PAY API. Below is the code for it..

```
 $receiver[] = array(
      'amount'  => '125.00',//amount to be transferred
      'email'  => 'seller@gmail.com',// paypal email id to which you want to send money
    );

$result = $paypal->call(
array(
'actionType'  => 'PAY',
'currencyCode'  => 'USD',
'feesPayer'  => 'EACHRECEIVER',
'memo'  => 'Withdrawal request no. 356',

'cancelUrl' => '/cancel.php',
'returnUrl' => '/success.php',
'senderEmail' => 'admin.business@gmail.com', // email id of admin's business account, from which amount will be transferred. 

'receiverList' => array(

  'receiver'=>$receiver
  )

 ), 'Pay'
); 

function call($values,$type)
  {
    $header = array(
  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".$config['userid'],
  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".$config['password'],
  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".$config['signature'],
  "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
  "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
  "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".$config['appid'];
   );

  $curl = curl_init("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/");
   $options = array(
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $header,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => json_encode($values),
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 10
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$rep = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($rep, true);
curl_close($curl);
return $response; 
  }
```

If you are the API caller and you specify your email address in the senderEmail field, PayPal sets the payment to be implicitly approved, without redirection to PayPal. (Alternatively, you can use sender.accountId.)

Comment: I'm trying to use PayPal Payouts with Java and am getting a 204 empty response as well. We were on Adaptive, but that never worked properly in Sandbox either. :\